# How can I create a random symmetric matrix in this way?

Tags: matrix, random

The most straight forward way for me to think about is like this:

```
H[N_] := RandomReal[{0,10},{N,N}]
symmetryH[N_]:=(H[N]+H[N]\[Transpose])/2
symmetryH[4]//MatrixForm
```

However, the above code does not work because the second call of `H[N]` will generate a different matrix from the first call. How can I get around this side effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you just have to create exactly one `H[N]` and use this 2 times. This can be achieved by

```
H[n_] := RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, n}]
symmetryH[n_] := With[{hn = H[n]},
  (hn + Transpose[hn])/2
]
```

Second, please do not use `N` as variable or pattern. It might shoot you in the foot because it is a function in *Mathematica*.

Finally, you should realize, that your approach contains a very serious flaw. What makes you believe, that you can calculate the mean of your matrix and its transpose while still maintain the same distribution for your randomness? Let us make a very quick example, where we create 1000 of your random matrices:

```
data = Table[symmetryH[4], {1000}];
```

Now, let us look on all upper left elements and plot their histogram

```
Histogram[data[[All, 1, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Exactly what you wanted. Evenly distributed. Let's take a look on the upper right corner

```
Histogram[data[[All, 1, -1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Uhh, not so nice. This happens because all upper right elements are really the mean of two different numbers, while the upper left elements are the mean of the same number.

Comment: You are very quick! :)

Comment: Sorry. Saw it and thought I need to clear this up as quick as possible so that no one believes it is a good way.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

This one prevents the distribution problems halirutan is talking about:

```
h[n_] :=
 Module[{m},
  m = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, n}];
  m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1, {n, n}] + 
    Transpose[m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i > j -> 1, {n, n}]] // Normal
  ]

h[5] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Distribution is uniform now:

```
Histogram@Flatten@h[1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sjoerd, rather than using `SparseArray` to obtain a lower vs. upper triangular matrix, I found that using `LowerTriangularize` and `UpperTriangularize` seems faster (and also more readable, at least to me). For instance, substituting `UpperTriangularize[m] + LowerTriangularize[Transpose@m, -1]` for your expression seems to give a roughly 100x speedup, at least on my system (v. 10.3).

Comment: @marcob you're fully right and I should have remembered this.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `Module` to declare a local variable:

```
H[N_] := RandomReal[{0,10},{N,N}]
symH[N_]:=Module[{h=H[N]},(h+h\[Transpose])/2];
symH[4]//MatrixForm
```

This should work.

Comment: No one upvote this poor answer... It is very convenient if one don't cares about the distribution....